# Convert interface{} to *[]int in golang

Tags: reflection, go, slice

I receive an interface which is basically a slice. Now I want to convert it to a pointer to the slice. The problem is, that I have either the slice itself or a Pointer to an interface.
I can easily show in a code example:

```
func main(){
    model := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,133123123123}
    method(model)
}

func method(model interface{}){ 
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(model))    // this is of type []int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&model))   // this is of type *interface{}
}
```

What I need is this type:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result))    // this should be type *[]int
```

I know the type only on runtime, therefore I cannot just take
    `&(model.([]int))`

Is there a way using golang reflection to receive this? the type 'int' is here actually not important, important is, that it is a **Pointer to a slice**. `*[]interface{}` would be okay either.

Edit:
To make the question more clear, I should have added: I am not interested in the data of the slice, but only in getting a pointer to a slice of same type (which can basically be empty). Therefore James Henstridge answers works perfectly.

Comment: What's wrong with http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr ? I admit I do not understand what you really want to do. It really depends. Not all values in Go **are** addressable, so it might be impossible to do. What do you want to do with a *[]int?

Comment: Indeed this value is not addressable.
Basically I want to create a slice of the predefined type (using reflect.MakeSlice) and pass it to a method of the library mgo (mgo's Query's All() method). This method needs a Ptr to Slice. I found a solution by creating the slice outside where type is known. But I'm trying to find a way to do this in a generic way inside.
Do I understand you right, that since it is not an addressable value, it is not possible to do this?

Comment: *everything* in go is passed by value. You can't get a pointer to `model` after you copied the value into the `method` call. It doesn't matter that it's an `interface{}` or not, you have slice value, not a pointer.

Comment: To add to JimB's comment, slices *act* like pointers in that they reference some block of memory and changing an element of the slice changes the memory so you see it in your caller, but *the slice variable itself* cannot change because THAT is passed as a value. The slice variable contains a pointer to the underlying memory and the length and capacity of the slice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before trying to answer the question, it is worth stepping back and asking what the `*[]int` value you're after should point at?

Given the way `method` is called we can't possibly get a pointer to the `model` variable from the calling context, since it will only receive a copy of the slice as its argument (note that this is a copy of the slice header: the backing array is shared).

We also can't get a pointer to the copy passed as an argument since it is stored as an `interface{}` variable: the interface variable owns the memory used to store its dynamic value, and is free to reuse it when the a new value is assigned to it.  If you could take a pointer to the dynamic value, this would break type safety if a different type is assigned.

We can obtain a `*[]int` pointer if we make a third copy of the slice, but it isn't clear whether that's what you'd necessarily want either:

```
v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model))
v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(model))
result := v.Interface()
```

This is essentially a type agnostic way of writing the following:

```
v := new([]int)
*v = model
var result interface{} = v
```

Now if you really wanted a pointer to the slice variable in the calling context, you will need to ensure that `method` is called with a pointer to the slice instead and act accordingly.

Comment: This is a great use of the reflect package.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I am basically not interested in the content of the slice's array (it is always empty in my use-case), but only in getting a slice of same type and a pointer to it.